# How do you do forEach in without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

How can I do this same functionality to es6?
I'm trying to add this text to the list item

```js
var names = [ "Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom" ];

$('#names-list li').each(function (index) {
 $(this).text(names[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="names-list">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"How can I do this same functionality to es6?"* Exactly the same. What's your point?

Comment: Did you mean "How do I do this without jQuery?" This question seems not so connected to ES6 per se.

Answer (score 6):

ES6 seems unrelated to what you're asking.

The gist of your question seems to be 'how do I achieve this without jQuery?'. In which case the equivalent would be to use `querySelectorAll()` to get the `li` elements, `forEach()` to loop over them and then set the `textContent`, like this:

```js
var names = ["Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom"];

document.querySelectorAll('#names-list li').forEach(function(li, index) {
  li.textContent = names[index];
});
```

```html
<ul id="names-list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ES6 and `querySelectorAll` are not really connected.

Comment: Perhaps, but I think the theme of the OP is 'how do I do this without jQuery'. I removed the reference to ES6 to save confusion.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ES6 doesn't really offer new ways to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I know - hence my previous comment about reading between the lines and saying the OP is asking how to have the same logic without jQuery.

Comment: I think this answer is excellent for the OP's purposes? Perhaps you could use `for in` instead of `forEach`, it's more readable in my opinion and it's ES6 :) `for(let i in elements) {
    els[i].innerText = names[i]
}`

Comment: I think jQuery `text()` method is more like setting `textContent` rather than `innerText` which will trigger a reflow and some other bad things.

Comment: @Kaiido I checked [the source](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.text), you're correct. I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't even know [NodeList.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) existed! Turns out it's *relatively* recent so polyfill may be required?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's `Array.prototype.forEach`, not `NodeList.prototype.forEach`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue my bad. One of those days :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 100% ES6, here you go:

```
const names = ["Jon", "Nick", "Bill", "Tom"];

const namesList = document.querySelectorAll("#names-list li");

for (let i in namesList) {
  namesList[i].innerText = names[i];
};
```

But I wouldn't really write the code like this if I were given any coding style.